# can't distinguish some arabic characters when querying in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I search about some arabic words in sql server , it doesn't distinguish between 'ة' and 'ت' and it shows them all

like in this picture

[image]

Comment: can you change collation to `Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS` and add `N` to your condition  `amp_firstname = N'...'` let me know if it worked - side note to change collation for the whole database `ALTER DATABASE myDatabaseName
COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS;` to change only for your column `Alter table myTableName alter column colName VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS`

Comment: @msoliman The alter database statement does not change the collation for "the whole database". It only changes the default collation - which will apply only to char columns created without a specific collation after the alter statement is run. Existing columns are completely unaffected by that statement.

Comment: The first command for altering database collate didn't work .. but I tried the second it worked but the result is still the same ..

Comment: use like 
where emp_firstname like n'نعمت'

Answer (score 2):

Try to `collate` them as

```
where emp_firstname collate Arabic_BIN = N'نعمت'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use N in your query to tell the sql engine that the following string is UNICODE.

```
WHERE EMP_FIRSTNAME = N'نعمت'
```

---

Here the function that convert the first letter only to Unicode. 
Both letters has a different code so it is weird how this happens with you.

```
DECLARE @STRING NCHAR(20) , @STRING1 NCHAR(20)
SET @STRING = N'ت'
SET @STRING1 = N'ة'
SELECT UNICODE(@STRING),@STRING , UNICODE(@STRING1) , @STRING1
```

Comment: the result is the same .. :-(